# Counting clicks on an <a> link in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have different links on my website which lead to other websites. I want to count the amount of clicks on the different links with my MySQL database. 
I thought about doing a redirection over a php file which adds it in the database, but I would prefer to not redirect the user. Is it possible that the user just clicks on the  tag gets immediately to the external website, and I can still count the click?

Thanks for you answers,
Till

Comment: try this https://mixpanel.com/

Comment: If your links open in a new tab/window, you could fire an on-click event and use AJAX to update the DB.

Comment: You either need to redirect everything via a PHP script like you mentioned, or have a JavaScript script that would send an AJAX request on click - would need to make sure the request is finished before taking the user to the next time as well. Or you could use Google Analytics, they have got comprehensive event tracking that does just that.

Comment: I know you said you want to know which link is clicked, but do you want to know how often a page is opened or really just want to collect clicks that happen on your own site?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can run an ajax request and when the request is completed then you can redirect user to where ever you want to.

in the ajax request you will count the clicks and save it to the database.
you can do something like

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "scriptthatwillcountclick.php", success: function(result){
        window.open('redirect_here');
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Ajax funcionality to accomplish your goal, just create an on click even for your "a" element and execute your Ajax to save the click information on your database.

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "save-my-click.php",
       data: { 'extrainfo' : "Some extra info" }
    });
});
```

Do not return false, or event.preventDefault() on your click event, because it will brake the redirection.

UPDATE:
**You don't need** to set the **success** and **error** functions because it is going to redirect anyway and you are not going to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax.

```
var data = {link:"value"}; 

$.ajax({
  url : "your_file.php",
  type: "POST",
  data : data,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log("error");
  }
});
```

You can run this code inside .click function when the link is pressed.
And in your php file just increment the count.

Comment: Thanks! but I have 10 different links which are added with a php loop from my MySQL database... Is it possible to send a number through the onclick function to ajax?

Comment: Yup for sure! You can just pass in a number to the data object.

`var data = {number: 1};`

And then in  your php file:

`$number = $_POST['number'];`